# How to collect heap dumps of any java process

Tags: java, heap-dump, thread-dump

I am new to Heaps , can anyone suggest how can i take heap dump of any java process (like Jmeter). I read about jmap command , but i am not getting where and how  to execute / write it (in eclipse or cmd). It might be a very basic question but still suggestions are requested.Can i download jmap.exe and jhat.exe from any where?
Thank You

Comment: Also whenever i execute on cmd Jmap command it shows jmap is not recognized as external or internal command.

Comment: I do this with Jvisualvm usually

Comment: If you use eclipse there is also the eclipse memory analyzer

Comment: Can i download jmap.exe and jhat.exe from any where?

Comment: Hi while using eclipse memory analyzer , in acquire heap dump window i am not able to add pid , can you tel me how to proceed.

Comment: jmap, jvisualvm, jconsole, etc. are all bundled with the JDK in the `bin` directory. On Windows, the path to this directory typically looks something like this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin`

Comment: Thank You when i run jmap < PID >in cmd it shows three col one shows path. Can anyone  tell what are other two. is it thread name and memory

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407612/how-to-get-a-thread-and-heap-dump-of-a-java-process-on-windows-thats-not-runnin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a thread and heap dump of a Java process on Windows that's not running in a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407612/how-to-get-a-thread-and-heap-dump-of-a-java-process-on-windows-thats-not-runnin)

Answer (score 12):

Here is the command:

```
<JDK_HOME>/jmap -F -dump:live,format=b,file=<file_name.hprof> <process_id>
```

You can mention the file location here in this command.

Comment: that's a valid answer but any idea why sometimes it fails for certain process id ? for example I get errors like : Attaching to process ID 23440, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

Comment: I have encountered that as well. Generally using the "-F" option works out there.

Comment: Yeah it does get generated but any idea why such errors pop up ?

Comment: @murasing - that's another question, already asked [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file)