# How to get the length of a type after serializization

Tags: java, bytesio

I encounter a problem that with Java, I have a map,such as `map<K,V>`, `K` and `V` can be arbitrary type, e.g `int`, `Long`, `String`, `Time`, etc.

After the map is serialized, can I get the length of `K` or the `V`? Can I write a common method to implement this idea? Something like:

```
public long getLength(object obj) {
    //how to get the length of this obj, obj can be any type
}
```

How could do that?

Comment: Serialization also implies serialization of the classes and fields, so values of some type having a fixed size is rarely valid.

Comment: What do you mean by the "length of a type"?

Comment: I mean any type(e.g Long int Time String...) after serializtion, how to get the bytes length， in the interface of Serializable，there's no method to get the length.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want to be able to find out *before* you serialize, how many bytes long the result would be *after*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Estimate serialization size of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069018/estimate-serialization-size-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**Nope.**

**But you can approximate though**, [here's a nice article about a sizeof function](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077408/core-java/sizeof-for-java.html).

**The reason is** that you can change the default binary serialization (which is kinda verbose). There are comparisons for these tools, the last time I was in this topic Kyro was the most optimal (10x smaller than the default Java binary serialization, because it does not neither export redundant nor anything verification-related data).

[image]

[Here's a comparison about the tools](https://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the length of an object after serialization except by serializing it.

Comment: hi Louis Wasserman, I want to get the bytes length after it is serialized.

Comment: Then you'll have to serialize it, and get the length of the resulting bytes.